# How to enable manually Unity keyboard layout switching

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout

In 12.04 I cannot use in Unity its default Keyboard layout switching mechanism. It doesn't matter how many and which layouts are added, only keyboard defined in xorgs (or possibly configurable manually using sudo setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle "us,cz") appears in system.
So what to check why it doesn't work or how to bind setxkbmap directly?

Answer (score 1):

To configure keyboard layout manually

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,cz
```

Comment: As I've written before, I can do this and I did. But I'd like to have a keyboard layout indicator on a panel. ScrollLock led was useful for this on xterm 15 years ago. Unity Keyboard indicator is much better. I'm asking for manual configuration of keyboard indicator or hwo to check why it doesn't work. Thanks.